# laptop screen is dead

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure

I have an old laptop hp NC6400, one day I accidentally drop it to the ground. The screen is dead since then. However, when I connected it to an external screen, the external screen can display everything.

Today I take my computer to the repair store to replace a screen, the manager see my screen is intact, and said to me: this is not the screen problem, it must be the computer's problem. You should look for a repair store to repair it. I told him that my computer can link to an external screen but he won't listen.

My question is, which part is the problem and how can I fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the screen doesn't work but an external monitor does, your first doubt should indeed be on the screen. However, there is a possibility that either the connector or the port that connects the screen to the motherboard is faulty. You can try the following (at your own risk):

1) Open the laptop and clean up everything, especially the parts where the screen is connected.

2) Attach and reattach the screen.

3) Make sure that no contact is bent or broken.

Other than that, there is not much you could do, since the connectors are mostly proprietary and you will need to buy a second display to test. You can try finding a junk laptop of a similar model with a working screen, but these are generally hard to come by.

Comment: However, there is a possibility that either the connector or the port that connects the screen to the motherboard is faulty. How to check this one? I've attach and reattach the screen several times...

Comment: Nothing to do but visual inspection. Maybe you could check for voltages around the area, but there is no real easy way of determining whether it is proper except attaching a working screen there.

Comment: I think I may need to use it as a desktop computer...